# Locked out of 15.04 after the latest update

Tags: updates, login, 15.04

An automatic update ran yesterday (7/7/2015) and now I am locked out of X windows.  The login screen has gone extra large, so the login box takes up a large part of the screen.  When I try and log in it accepts the password, then dumps me back to the login screen.  I can switch to the terminal with ctrl-alt-F1 and log in OK so there is no issue with my password, but then I am stuck in text mode.

How do I fix this?

**Update:**

I think I found the cause in syslog:

```
Xlib: extension "GLX" missing on display:
gnome-session-is-accelerated: No hardware 3D support
gnome-session-check-accelerated: Helper exited with code 256
gnome-session[...]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry...
lightdm[...]: ** lightdm CRITICAL **: session_get_login1_session_id: assertion 'session!=NULL' failed
```

So it appears that it is failing because it is not getting 3D acceleration, despite having an Nvidia GTX 960 card.

But I still have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem and fixed it by removing all nvidia drivers:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*
```

(The glob didn't expand here so you might need to type them all..)

Booting with `nouveau.modeset=0` added to the linux line in the grub. (Press E at the grub menu entry and add the text)

Login in to the system, right clicking for at terminal and running:

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

and

```
setsid unity
```

After this I reinstalled the nvidia drivers via the additional drivers menu.

Hope it helps!